# Not able to select values from right list using LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two list `list_1` and `list_2` mentioned below respectively.

List 1:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "O1",
        "VId": "V2"
    },
    {
        "Id": "O2",
        "VId": "V2"
    },
    {
        "Id": "O3",
        "VId": "V2"
    }
]
```

List 2:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "O1",
        "VId": "V1"
    },
    {
        "Id": "O3",
        "VId": "V1"
    }
]
```

I am joining these two list using the query below.

```
var query = from obj_1 in list_1
join obj_2 in list_2
on obj_1.Id equals obj_2.Id into objCombined
from combinedObj in objCombined.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new Info {Id = obj_1.Id, S_VId = obj_1.VId, T_VId = combinedObj?.VId ?? null};
```

The result I get is this.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "O1",
        "S_VId": "V2",
        "T_VId": "V2" // want value as V1 here
    },
    {
        "Id": "O2",
        "S_VId": "V2",
        "T_VId": null // This is correct
    },
    {
        "Id": "O3",
        "VId": "V2",
        "T_VId": "V2" // want value as V1 here
    }
]
```

`combinedObj` that is getting populated is from `list_1`, that's why value I get in my output for `T_VId` is V2, I want the value of T_VId top be taken from `list_2` and be V1.

How should I write the query to achieve this?

Comment: can you add an example of the exit that you would like?

Comment: @Iria : T_VId property should have the value of Vid property of list_2. i.e. V1

Comment: As expected, I can't reproduce this issue ([example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y1nSaq)), so I'm voting to close.

Comment: arg, incoherent variables names.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working sample:

```
var distinctIds = list1.Concat(list2).Select(x => x.Id).Distinct();
var result = distinctIds.Select(x => new Info()
{
    Id = x,
    S_VId = list1.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x)?.VId,
    T_VId = list2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x)?.VId
});
```

Comment: This code isn't equivalent to OP's code and OP's code works.